# TSQL data types incompatible in the subtract operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I'm using a while loop to iterate through some tables and carry out a replace on a field, to remove all the hyphens. All of the fields are varchar.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (TableName VARCHAR(max),Id int identity(1,1))
INSERT INTO @Table
Select distinct table_name From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
DECLARE @max int
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @id int = 1
select @max = MAX(Id) from @Table
WHILE (@id <= @max) 
BEGIN
    SELECT @TableName = TableName FROM @Table WHERE Id = @id
    SET @SQL = 'update '+ @TableName +' set colA = replace(colA,'-','');'
    EXEC(@SQL)
SET @id = @id +1
END
```

the error I receive is:

> The data types varchar(max) and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

I've tried changing the varchar variables to fixed lengths or all to max, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use two single quotes when creating a single quote inside of a string:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (TableName VARCHAR(max),Id int identity(1,1))
INSERT INTO @Table
Select distinct table_name From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
DECLARE @max int
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @id int = 1
select @max = MAX(Id) from @Table
WHILE (@id <= @max) 
BEGIN
    SELECT @TableName = TableName FROM @Table WHERE Id = @id
    SET @SQL = 'update '+ @TableName +' set colA = replace(colA,''-'','''');'
    EXEC(@SQL)
SET @id = @id +1
END
```